# how to improve cold query besides compiled query

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have a Find API on my repository, and compiled query is not working as expected. The query has several IEnumerable.Contains(), so the compilation result in a SQL with no where-in statement and all the contains are evaluated locally.

I know Entity Framework 6 supports view pre-generation, does Entity Framework core have similar concept? If not, what would be the next trick to use to improve cold query performance?

[Update]
This is for illustration only

```cs
var typeIds = new int[] { 1, 2 };
var allTypeIds = !typeIds.Any();
var subTypeIds = new int[0];
var allSubTypeIds = !subTypeIds.Any();
var navEntityIds = new int[0];
var allNavEntityIds = !navEntityIds.Any();

var result = dbContext.Entities.Where(e =>
    (allTypeIds || typeIds.Contains(e.TypeId))
    && (allSubTypeIds || subTypeIds.Contains(e.SubTypeId))
    && (allNavEntityIds || navEntityIds.Contains(e.NavigationEntityId)))
    .Include(e => e.Type)
    .Include(e => e.SubType)
    .Include(e => e.NavigationEntity)
    .Include(e => e.ExtendedEntities)
    .ToList();
```

[Update2] The compiled version

```cs
var searchParam = new SearchParam();
searchParam.TypeIds = new int[] { 1, 2 };
searchParam.AllTypeIds = !searchParam.TypeIds.Any();
searchParam.SubTypeIds = new int[0];
searchParam.AllSubTypeIds = !searchParam.SubTypeIds.Any();
searchParam.NavEntityIds = new int[0];
searchParam.AllNavEntityIds = !searchParam.NavEntityIds.Any();

var compiledQuery = EF.CompileQuery<MyDbContext, SearchParam, Entity>((ctx, sp) =>
    ctx.Entities.Where(e =>
        (sp.AllTypeIds || sp.TypeIds.Contains(e.TypeId))
        && (sp.AllSubTypeIds || sp.SubTypeIds.Contains(e.SubTypeId))
        && (sp.AllNavEntityIds || sp.NavEntityIds.Contains(e.NavigationEntityId)))
        .Include(e => e.Type)
        .Include(e => e.SubType)
        .Include(e => e.NavigationEntity)
        .Include(e => e.ExtendedEntities));
var result = compiledQuery.Invoke(dbContext, searchParam)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think there is. May be you should investigate what is causing the client evaluation and how to avoid it. It would be nice if you provide some code.

Comment: I am guessing Contains() cannot be compiled causing the need to evaluate it locally. Without compilation, I do not get the local evaluation warning/exception.

Comment: or may be because of the compilation it self: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13976

Comment: Depends on `Contains`. If it is on `IEnumerable<primitive_type>` parameter, looks like it's not causing client evaluation on compiled query (at least in EFC 2.2). Can you include the sample compiled query as well?

Comment: Would int? be considered primitive? one of the columns can be null so that is why I have to use that.

Comment: Yes, it should work with `int?` as well. The compiled query looks ok. I've tried something similar and it translates well in 2.2 - can't test 2.1, hence can't say what's the problem with yours. Anyway, back to the original question - there is no query pre-generation. And actually I'm unsure `CompileQuery` will improve the "cold startup" - the benefits if any will be for the consecutive calls. Cheers.